# Rails: Remove element from array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following array:

```
 array = [{"email"=>"test@test.com", "name"=>"Test"},
          {"email"=>"testA@test.com", "name"=>"Test A"},
          {"name"=>"Test B", "email"=>"testB@test.com"},
          {"email"=>"testC@test.com", "name"=>"Test C"},
          {"name"=>"Test D", "email"=>"testD@test.com"},
          {"email"=>"testE@test.com"},
          {"name"=>"Test F", "email"=>"testF@test.com"}]
```

I have a list of "blacklist" emails, for instance:

```
 blacklist = ["testC@test.com"]
```

I want to do something like this:

```
 array - blacklist 
 # => should remove element {"email"=>"testC@test.com", "name"=>"Test C"}
```

Surely there is a sexy-Ruby way to do this with .select or something, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  I tried this to no avail:

```
 array.select {|k,v| v != "testC@test.com"} # => returns array without any changes
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
filtered_array = array.reject { |h| blacklist.include? h['email'] }
```

or if you want to use [`select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) instead of [`reject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) (perhaps you don't want to hurt anyone's feelings):

```
filtered_array = array.select { |h| !blacklist.include? h['email'] }
```

Your

```
array.select {|k,v| ...
```

attempt won't work because array hands the Enumerable blocks a single element and that element will be a Hash in this case, the `|k,v|` trick would work if `array` had two element arrays as elements though.

Comment: brilliant! thanks for the quick turnaround :)   in fact, you answered so quickly that I can't even "accept" the answer on SO's system.

Comment: there is also an exclude function that is and alias for !include

Comment: @Darren: The only downside is that [`exclude?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-exclude-3F) is a Rails extension and that would lead into double negative territory :) I'd probably go with the `reject`/`include?`.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
array.delete_if {|key, value| value == "testC@test.com" }
```

Comment: similar to @mu is too short's `select`, it should be `array.delete_if {|hash| hash["email"] == "testC@test.com"}`

Comment: delete_if works inplace (usually not a good idea), the OP seems to want a new array.